# Set Maui to schedule jobs with maximum CPU percentage

Tags: cluster-computing, cpu, schedule, torque

I use Torque/Maui to manage/schedule jobs, I want to maintain the CPU usage under 90%. I notice in [Appendix C: Node manager (MOM) configuration](http://www.nordugrid.org/documents/pbs-config.html), `ideal_load` and `max_load` are not appropriate to do this. how could I do this?

Comment: anybody tell me what is wrong with this question?

Comment: What scheduler do you use to start the jobs? TORQUE doesn't schedule jobs. Usually TORQUE is used with Moab, Maui, or pbs_sched.

Comment: There may be a way for Maui to consider a node as occupied once it hits a certain CPU usage threshold but you'd have to look through the Maui docs.

Answer (score 0):

It occurred to me that there is a way to accomplish this using TORQUE independent of your scheduler if doing this through the scheduler is impossible: you can use a [node health checker](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/4-1-4/Content/topics/11-troubleshooting/computeNodeHealthCheck.htm). There are many different ways to configure this, but essentially you can write a script that checks the CPU usage on the machine and echoes an error if it goes to 90% or higher. Then, configure that script as the node health check script for each node and you will get the nodes marked unavailable for new jobs whenver the CPU is above that threshold.